Save a rendered image in a new datablock (NOT in a new file)
I'd like to use the rendered image (frame extracted from a video) and save it in a new datablock (NOT in a new file). Is this possible? If I create a new image from the viewer, then I cannot copy/paste the rendered image to this new image, and if I just rename the image & add a fake user, this does not work (e.g. the image is replaced next time I render something).
